# If/Else curl command not working

Tags: bash, if-statement, curl

I am using a grep -c to count the occurrence of a phrase on a curl. Currently the code below return a number 12.

```
curl WEBSITEURL | grep -c "incident-title"
```

I want to use this in a single line if/else bash command that says that if the occurrence is greater than 0 then printf or else printf.

```
if curl WEBSITEURL | grep -c "incident-title" > 0; then printf "Investigating Issue"; else printf "Fully Operational"; fi
```

It keeps returning "Fully Operational" even though that it should be true as 12 is greater than 0.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem in need of a "one-liner", here is the same idea, but embedded inside of an `if/else` block.

```
if (( $( curl $WEBSITEURL | grep -c "incident-title" ) > 0 )) ; then printf "Investigating Issue"; else printf "Fully Operational"; fi
```

IHTH

Answer (score 5):

Don't count the number of lines output by `grep`; just check that its exit status is 0, which indicates at least one successful match.

```
if curl WEBSITEURL | grep -q "incident-title"; then
    printf "Investigating Issue"
else
    printf "Fully Operational"
fi
```

The `-q` suppresses standard output, because you don't care what the match is, only that there is a match.

Answer (score 4):

`>` means output redirection in the shell. If you want to compare numbers in bash, use the arithmetic expansion (and command substitution to capture the output):

```
if (( $(curl WEBSITEURL | grep -c "incident-title") > 0 )) ; then
```

I'd use a variable for readability if it's not a one-off thing

```
n=$(curl WEBSITEURL | grep -c "incident-title")
if (( n > 0 )) ; then
    printf %s 'Investigating Issue'
else
    printf %s 'Fully Operational'
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the other answers provided, here's a suggestion. Try using short-circuit logical operators `&&` and `||`. You may shorten your code to:

```
(( $(curl WEBSITEURL | grep -c "incident-title") > 0 )) && printf 'Investigating Issue' || printf 'Fully Operational'
```

This however is harder to read compared to multiple lines of `if...else...fi`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for assisting. I truly appreciate it. I was looking for a one-liner and shellter provide the one-liner that resolved my issue.